# Hierarchial Query Oracle SQL, get relation from both sides

Tags: sql, oracle

Lets say we have the following relationships

| friend_from | friend_to |
| --- | --- |
| BOB | JOHAN |
| TRACY | JOHAN |

How can i use an hierarchical query to get all rows that are related to 'BOB'. So basically an BI-directional query.

Expected Result:

| friend_from | friend_to |
| --- | --- |
| BOB | JOHAN |
| TRACY | JOHAN |

My query:

```
  SELECT friend_from, friend_to
  FROM friends
  start with friend_from='BOB'
  CONNECT BY PRIOR friend_from = friend_to;/
```

This only returns

| friend_from | friend_to |
| --- | --- |
| BOB | JOHAN |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a larger sample data set to fully describe the problem but I think, if you want to connect on both sides of the relationship then you can use:

```
SELECT friend_from,
       friend_to
FROM   friends
START WITH friend_from = 'BOB'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR friend_from IN (friend_from, friend_to)
OR     PRIOR friend_to   IN (friend_from, friend_to);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE friends (friend_from, friend_to) AS
SELECT 'BOB',   'JOHAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'TRACY', 'JOHAN' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| FRIEND_FROM | FRIEND_TO |
| --- | --- |
| BOB | JOHAN |
| TRACY | JOHAN |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q5w6vlqy)

Comment: NB: It works because 'BOB' is a a 'friendly_from', if you start with 'JOHAN' it doesn't return anything and if you "START WITH friend_from = 'JOHAN' OR friend_to = 'JOHAN'", you will get duplicated rows.